# How to pass Multiple Image in form and catch in controller?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have input tag in my form that get multiple image, but when I post form to my controller only last image passed.

this is my form

```
<form class="floating-labels m-t-40" method="post" action="{{asset(route('products.store'))}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }} ">
<input type="file" name="other_file[]" id="images" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

when I `dd($request)` in my controller 
only show last image details.

Is there any hope?

Comment: Interesting. What's the output of `dd($request->file('other_file'));`?

Comment: only last image details :(         

array:1 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#290 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "blog-8-1.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    inode: 0
    size: 134154
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php4323.tmp"
  }
]

Comment: check $_FILES , and also in network tab check what is send

Comment: still pass last image :(

Answer (score 1):

For me It works like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('attachment'))
{
    $files = $request->file('attachment');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
       .....
    }
}
```

The html part

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple>
```